# checking form control input for errors by using it as a variable

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angular8, mat-input

I'm using angular 8 with angular material to write my website.

I have a form with `formGroup` created and I want to be able to use `*ngIf` to check for validation errors by using the actual input element as a parameter.

currently this is my working code:

I have the following form:

```
<form [formGroup]="queryForm" (submit)="runQuery()">
...
  <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput #timezone placeholder="Timezone" aria-label="Timezone" formControlName="timePeriodTimeZone"/>
            <mat-hint>timezone as a number</mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('timePeriodTimeZone','required')">timezone required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
...
</form>
```

and in the class of the component I implemented the `hasError()` function like this:

```
 public hasError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) =>{
    return this.queryForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }
```

and of course I configured the `queryForm` variable as a group created by form builder.

is there a way to check the error without calling a function from the class itself?

since I added `#timezone` to the input field I assumed i will be able to do something like:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="timezone.hasError('required')">timezone required!</mat-error>
```

but I can't! :)

I would prefer to use something like that cause I want to create an error handling component with some mat-errors so I will be able to reuse it in each input field and I would like to paste to it the input control instead of the entire form group.

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you know that if the field has a unique validator, you can use simply

```
<mat-error>timezone required!</mat-error>
```

(the *ngIf is not necesary).

if you want has a big control of errors, you can has some like

```
<mat-error >{{getError('timezone')}}</mat-error>
```

and you has a function like

```
getError(field:string)
{
   const control=this.myForm.get(field);
   string error=''
   switch (field)
    case 'timezone':
       error=control.hasError('required')?'time zone required':
              control.hasError('other')?' other error':''
    break;
    case '....'
   }
   return error;
}
```